# determining disk space usage on plesk domain

Tags: unix, domain, disk-space-utilization

I have an unix webserver runing Plesk control panel with several domains configured.
Plesk is reporting that one of the domains is using 1129 mb of disk space, however, I can't seem to find what exacly is taking so much space.

I've logged in into the server using ssh and checked the size of the /var/www/vhosts/[domain] directory and it has only 360 mb.

So, my question is, does plesk store any data from the vhosts outside that directory? What could be taking so much space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to go and see detailed statistic reported in Plesk. It will normally split it into several categories, so for example you could see the space is consumed by domain backups.

Generally the following content is counted, but not located in `/var/www/vhosts/[domain]`:

1. databases
2. mail accounts
3. Java applications (TomCat)
4. backup files

Generally any of these categories can take a lot of space, though backup files and databases would be most common.

Comment: It was in fact a misconfiguration with the backup system that was filling up the disk. Thanks.